# Appstore iOS warning ITMS-90076: Potential Loss of Keychain Access

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I have App Store Connect issues, after when I **transferred** application another account.

> ITMS-90076: Potential Loss of Keychain Access - The previous version
> of software has an application-identifier value of ['test.iosapp'] and
> the new version of software being submitted has an
> application-identifier of ['newTest.iosapp']. This will result in a
> loss of keychain access.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Are you using the keychain in your app?

Comment: Yes, I use keychain.

Comment: development team changed and what can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was resolved after we put a new build on the account

Answer (score 1):

Don’t change the application identifier.

And are you really going to change “test.iOSapp” to “NewTest.iOSapp”? Please do everyone a favour and get a proper name at least that you can stay with. Or better, stay with test.iOSapp.

Comment: development team changed and what can I do ?